# Android Java String to Blob

Tags: java, php, android

I am trying to convert a string to blob like this:

```
 byte[] byteArray = myFile.getBytes("UTF-8");//Better to specify encoding
            Blob blobData = null;
            blobData.setBytes(1, byteArray);
```

The string contains my pdf file like this

```
 BufferedReader input = null;
            input = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(openFileInput(myFile)));
            String line;
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }
            String text = buffer.toString();

            byte[] byteArray = text.getBytes("UTF-8");

            Blob blobData = null;

            blobData.setBytes(1, byteArray);
```

In my PHP-File I retrieve the blob like this

```
$pdf=$_GET['pdf']
$statement = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO kunden(kunden_plz, kunden_nachname, kunden_vorname, kunden_adresse, kunden_ort, kunden_email, kunden_pdf) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

$statement->bind_param("sssssss", $postleitzahl, $firstname,$lastname,$citytext,$address,$e_mail,$pdf );
$statement->execute();
```

My database is not getting the params

Answer (score 0):

The line `myFile.getBytes("UTF-8")` doesn't read the file content, but only encodes the file path into byte[].

Check [this](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Persisting-Data-to-the-Device#local-files) resource to learn about file IO.

Comment: Ty for your the tip! I changed my code according to the linked website, but I still have the problem with  delivering the blob to the php file

Comment: I don't see how you are passing the data to the server. Probably with a POST request. But, you don't need to use `Blob`. Once you have the byte[] just write it to the connection as a request body.